# How can I copy and paste my beautifully indented code into my notebook without alteration?

Tags: import, notebooks, formatting, copy-as, code-organization

Say I indent my code like this:

```
Which[
 {x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1},
 {
  pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
  pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
  pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
  message = "Gameover", DotT = {2, (4 - .3)},
  DotL = {2, (2 + .3)}, DotB = {2, (0 + .3)}, Switch = False
  },
 {x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2},
 {
  pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
  pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
  pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
  message = "Stay in place"
  },
 {x1, y1 + 1} == {x3, y3},
 {
  Which[
   Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 + 1}}] == {{x3, y3 + 1}},
   {
    pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}},
    pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}},
    pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}},
    message = "Stay in place"}, {x3, y3 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1},
   {
    pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}},
    pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}},
    pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}},
    message = "Gameover",
    DotT = {2, (4 - .3)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .3)}, DotB = {2, (0 + .3)},
    Switch = False
    },
   Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 + 1}}] != {{x3, y3 + 1}},
   {
    pos1 = pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 + 1}},
    pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2 - 1}},
    pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3 + 1}},
    message = "Conga"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

It's very clear and human-readable for me this way, however, when I copy and paste this into my notebook I get this:

```
Which[{x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1}, {pos1 = 
   pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}}, 
  pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}}, 
  pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}}, message = "Gameover",
   DotT = {2, (4 - .3)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .3)}, DotB = {2, (0 + .3)}, 
  Switch = False}, {x1, y1 + 1} == {x2, y2}, {pos1 = 
   pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}}, 
  pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}}, 
  pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}, 
  message = "Stay in place"}, {x1, y1 + 1} == {x3, y3}, {Which[
   Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 + 1}}] == {{x3, y3 + 1}}, {pos1 = 
     pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1}}, 
    pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2}}, 
    pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3}}, 
    message = "Stay in place"}, {x3, y3 + 1} == {x2, y2 - 1}, {pos1 = 
     pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = 2, y1 = 2}}, 
    pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = 2, y2 = 4}}, 
    pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = 2, y3 = 0}}, 
    message = "Gameover", DotT = {2, (4 - .3)}, DotL = {2, (2 + .3)}, 
    DotB = {2, (0 + .3)}, Switch = False}, 
   Intersection[bound, {{x3, y3 + 1}}] != {{x3, y3 + 1}}, {pos1 = 
     pos1 /. {{x1, y1} -> {x1 = x1, y1 = y1 + 1}}, 
    pos2 = pos2 /. {{x2, y2} -> {x2 = x2, y2 = y2 - 1}}, 
    pos3 = pos3 /. {{x3, y3} -> {x3 = x3, y3 = y3 + 1}}, 
    message = "Conga"}]}]
```

Which is complete garbage for my eyes. How can I retain the beauty?

Comment: Reindenting slows my progress...

Comment: The thing is, I indented my code originally in the .nb file, but I didn't save it as a .nb file. I just copied this indented code and pasted it into notepad and saved it as a .txt file, closed the .nb file without saving, and then later copied and pasted my indented .txt code into a new .nb file and then reindented, but this process is becoming monstrous. If I save as a .nb file. then will it retain the indentation when I reopen the file? The reason I did this .txt business was because I was accessing Mathematica on a remote machine and had no way of saving files to my local machine.

Comment: I doub't MMA's formatting can be completely overridden, though if it can someone is sure to respond. Nonetheless, requiring indentation for readability tends to be a symptom of using non-functional idioms... Also, what's with `Switch=False`? You do realize `Switch` is an MMA reserved symbol, yes?

Comment: I think pasting into a notebook filters the incoming data and reformats it. Like newlines...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The answer to Meta Mathematica question [1493](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/copy-code-block-from-se-to-mma-without-loss-of-line-breaks) may be of help to you.  At a minimum, it allows you to copy code from Mathematica StackExchange to a notebook without loss of formatting.

Comment: Well that kind of works. I copied the .txt code into a .nb file with style set to "code" and then selected all the code in the .nb file and changed the style to "input", but I don't get the same experience.

Comment: I have used this procedure described only to copy code between StackExchange and a notebook, which otherwise garbles formatting.  I do not know whether it works more generally.

Comment: @Sam why did you switch to Input ? Code style exists specifically to have your own indentation and allows to run code is Input cell does.

Answer (score 4):

I know a very awkward way to make an Input cell which behaves the way you are looking for. It has different editing properties.

I came across such cells when importing notebooks from very long ago. They were from the mid 1990's either Mathematica 3 or Mathematica 4 and they had editing properties, which I still miss very much today.

Here I show you a normal InputCell and a modified one:

[image: normal InputCell and a modified one without BoxData]

I really do not know what makes the difference. The modified cell uses InputForm

[image: Cell>ConvertTo-Properties]

and it does not show syntax highlighting, it also avoids half spaces (probably because I changed everything to monospaced Courier font and also suppressed less than one space appearing in things written in a monospaced font. Unfortunately I do not remember which of the zillions of OptionInspector Settings it was).

**How to make a cell with these fancy properties (unfortunately awkward to do)**

1. Make a normal input cell as you always do.
2. press Shift Ctl E. You get something like

   Cell[BoxData["[IndentingNewLine]"], "Input",
   CellChangeTimes->{3.6631740883686132`*^9}]

   (the strange number is the timestamp of when you made the cell. If you edit it later, the time stamps of all these changes yield a list of edit timestamps.)
3. Now modify this to (i.e. get rid of BoxData[], but leave the quotation marks)

   Cell["", "Input",
   CellChangeTimes->{3.6631740883686132`*^9}]
4. Now press Shift Ctl E again.
5. Now you may enter what you like into this cell. I show you an example in my favourite intentation style: all matching braces, brackets, curly braces and the colons from the same level go into the same column, if they all do not fit onto a single line. This type of indentation makes it easy to check balance, however we get such strange things as lines starting with a colon, since I regard the colonsin some construct [ ..., ..., ...]  to be on the same level as the brackets (same holds for braces of any type). Here an example:

[image: InputCell with my favourite indentation]

**Advantages of these modified InputCells:**

1. You may indent as you like it best.
2. You may use tab to offset a comment from your code.
3. you may use tab even in the code itself.

**Disadvantage**

1. Awkward to produce (unless you make one cell of this type and split it using Schift Ctl D).
2. No Syntax Highlighting
3. Bound to InputForm. (I got used to that.)

They behave identical to normal InputCells, as far as I have observed. One can make them e.g. InitializationCells and so forth.

It would be nice, if someone out in this forum could shine some light in what really happens under the hood and possibly show us a way to create such cells with a single keystroke. I got the impression that using Cell>ConvertTo only exposes you to the hazard of loosing all your thoroughly written comments but does not give you cells where space and tab behave like in Mousepad, Notepad or any other text editor for monospaced text.